# Clamav. WARNING: No clamd server appears to be available

Tags: linux, logging, clamav, milter

I have clamav.log full of these messages, what might be the problem and how to fix this? 
I have Debian
clamav-0.97.6+dfsg-1~squeeze1
spamassassin-3.3.1-1
dovecot-pop3d-1.2.15-7
postfix-2.7.1-1+squeeze1
and also there is somewhere near milter.

**LocalSocket setting is ok**

```
Tue Jun  4 07:43:34 2013 -> WARNING: No clamd server appears to be available
Tue Jun  4 07:44:34 2013 -> WARNING: No clamd server appears to be available
Tue Jun  4 07:45:34 2013 -> WARNING: No clamd server appears to be available
Tue Jun  4 07:46:34 2013 -> WARNING: No clamd server appears to be available
Tue Jun  4 07:47:34 2013 -> WARNING: No clamd server appears to be available
Tue Jun  4 07:47:58 2013 -> ERROR: Failed to initiate streaming/fdpassing
Tue Jun  4 07:47:58 2013 -> WARNING: No clamd server appears to be available
Tue Jun  4 07:48:58 2013 -> WARNING: No clamd server appears to be available
Tue Jun  4 07:49:33 2013 -> ERROR: Failed to initiate streaming/fdpassing
Tue Jun  4 07:49:33 2013 -> WARNING: No clamd server appears to be available
```

Comment: @MichaelHampton, yup it seems to solve the problem. I am using ISPManager and I thought after installing it will start the clamd right away, so didn't checked this option. You can post it as an answer, so i'll accept :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clamd server doesn't appear to be running. Try starting it.

Answer (score 0):

Check equally:

/etc/clamav/clamd.conf

```
...
LocalSocket /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl
...
```

And

/etc/clamav/clamav-milter.conf

```
...
ClamdSocket unix:/var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl
...
```

Answer (score 0):

When there is an issue with clamd@scan service, because the user changed from clam to clamscan try this solution: (ATTENTION!!! THIS IS A SOLUTION FOR Red Hat, CentOS, Fedora family distros).

```
# sudo mkdir -p /var/log/clamav
```

---

Make sure the /var/lib/clamav & /var/log/clamav with the right user & group.

```
# sudo chown -R clamscan:clamscan /var/lib/clamav
# sudo chown -R clamscan:clamscan /var/log/clamav
```

---

Open the file /etc/freshclam.conf and make sure the lines are set to as below:

```
# sudo nano /etc/freshclam.conf
```

Find and check does it contain this: (use ctrl+w)

```
DatabaseDirectory /var/lib/clamav
DatabaseOwner clamscan
```

---

```
#sudo nano /etc/clamd.conf
```

Find and check does it contain this: (use ctrl+w)

```
LogFile /var/log/clamav/clamd.scan
DatabaseDirectory /var/lib/clamav
User clamscan
```

---

```
# sudo nano /etc/clamd.d/scan.conf
```

Find and check does it contain this: (use ctrl+w)

```
LocalSocket /var/run/clamd.scan/clamd.sock
```

---

```
# sudo nano /etc/mail/clamav-milter.conf
```

Find and check does it contain this: (use ctrl+w)

```
ClamdSocket unix:/var/run/clamd.scan/clamd.sock
```

---

If someone is using clamav milter and has an issue.

```
# sudo chown -R clamilt:clamilt /var/run/clamav-milter/clamav-milter.socket
# sudo chown -R clamilt:clamilt /var/run/clamav-milter/
# sudo chmod 775 /var/run/clamav-milter/clamav-milter.socket
# sudo chmod -R 775 /var/run/clamav-milter/
# sudo getfacl /var/run/clamav-milter/clamav-milter.socket
# sudo getfacl /var/run/clamav-milter/
```

---

Restart will take up to 2 minutes or longer, just wait. It should start itself.

```
# sudo systemctl restart clamd@scan
# sudo freshclam
```

---

Check the status:

```
# sudo systemctl status clamd@scan
```

Answer (score -2):

Fedora 19 : systemctl , sendmail & clamav-milter :

http://pantestmb.blogspot.ro/2013/10/fedora-19-systemctl-sendmail-clamav.html

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.